# How do I keep special characters which searching for term frequencies?

Tags: r

I have a document out of which I have special characters along with text such as `!`, `#`, `@`, `$`, `%` and more. The following code is used to obtain the most frequent terms list. But when it is performed, the special characters are missing in the frequent terms list i.e. if `"#StackOverFlow"` is the word present 100 times in the document, I get it as `"StackOverFlow"` without `#` in the frequent terms list. Here is my code:

```
review_text <- paste(rome_1$text, collapse=" ")
#The special characters are present within review_text
review_source <- VectorSource(review_text)
corpus <- Corpus(review_source)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm2 <- as.matrix(dtm)
frequency <- colSums(dtm2)
frequency <- sort(frequency, decreasing = TRUE)
head(frequency)
```

Where exactly have I gone wrong here?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. You're likely using non-base packages and we don't know your input...it's hard to give help in these conditions...

Comment: I used this text : review_text <- paste("I love watching #AXN , said @ Anita. I love the soaps on #AXN" , collapse=" ") and I get results as expected by you with #s and other special characters included . Can you post a piece of text which you are using.For example #axn gets a count of 2

Comment: I had to include a space after Anita in the above comment, otherwise was not allowed to post !

Comment: @Indi Even with the text you've specified, I get the same result of AXNwith a count of 2 instead of #AXN. Also, I've tried encoding it to UTF-8 but the response is the same. Although, `review_text` shows the text correctly with #AXN

Comment: @digEmAll  Sorry for the delayed response. The text specified above provides the same response. I'm using the `tm` library and nothing else along with it.

Comment: I checked out `dtm2` in the code above with the text given by @Indi above. It shows as axn in `dtm2` instead of `#AXN`. Does that provide any answers about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the DocumentTermMatrix documentation :

> This is different for a SimpleCorpus. In this case all options are
>   processed in a fixed order in one pass to improve performance. **It
>   always uses the Boost Tokenizer (via Rcpp) and takes no custom
>   functions as option arguments.**

It seems that `SimpleCorpus` objects (created by `Corpus` function) use a pre-defined Boost tokenizer which automatically splits words removing punctuations (including `#`).

You could use VCorpus instead, and removes the punctuations characters you want e.g. :

```
library(tm)
review_text <- 
"I love #StackOverflow. #Stackoverflow is great, but Stackoverflow exceptions are not!"

review_source <- VectorSource(review_text)
corpus <- VCorpus(review_source) # N.B. use  VCorpus here !!
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
patternRemover <- content_transformer(function(x,patternToRemove) gsub(patternToRemove,'',x))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, patternRemover, '\\!|\\.|\\,|\\;|\\?') # remove only !.,;?

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize='words'))
dtm2 <- as.matrix(dtm)
frequency <- colSums(dtm2)
frequency <- sort(frequency, decreasing = TRUE)
```

Result :

```
> frequency
#stackoverflow     exceptions          great           love  stackoverflow 
             2              1              1              1              1
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thanks a million. If I were to use Corpus instead of VCorpus, can I achieve this?

Comment: If you pass VectorSource or DirSource to Corpus function, it will return a SimpleCorpus... so I suggest you to use VCorpus function directly instead of Corpus.